# Optionally taking the first item in a sequence

Tags: f#, sequence, idioms

I need a function like `Seq.head`, but returning `None` instead of throwing an exception when the sequence is empty, i.e., `seq<'T> -> 'T option`.

There are a jillion ways to do this. Here are several:

```
let items = Seq.init 10 id
let a = Seq.tryFind (fun _ -> true) items
let b = Seq.tryPick Some items
let c = if Seq.isEmpty items then None else Some (Seq.head items)
let d = 
  use e = items.GetEnumerator()
  if e.MoveNext() then Some e.Current
  else None
```

`b` is the one I use. Two questions:

1. Is there a particularly idiomatic way to do this?
2. Since there's no built-in `Seq.tryHead` function, does that indicate this shouldn't be necessary, is uncommon, or is better implemented without a function?

#### UPDATE

[`tryHead` has been added to the standard library in F# 4.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/commit/b10392dc16593bf9286583e2a87217d18fa18b8a).

Comment: There is a Seq.tryHead in the following library FSharpx.Collections http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharpx.Collections/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think (b) is probably the most idiomatic, for the same reason @Ramon gave.

I think the lack of `Seq.tryHead` just means that it is not super common.

I'm not sure, but my guess is that functional languages with Hindley-Milner type inference in general are sparse about implementing such specific functions on collection types because overloading isn't available and composing higher-order functions can be done tersely.

For example, C# Linq extensions are much more exhaustive than functions in F#'s `Seq` module (which itself is more exhaustive than functions on concrete collection types), and even has `IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault`. Practically every overload has a variation which performs a `map`.

I think emphasis on pattern matching and concrete types like `list` is also a reason.

Now, most of the above is speculation, but I think I may have a notion closer to being objective. I think a lot of the time `tryPick` and `tryFind` can be used in the first place instead of `filter |> tryHead`. For example, I find myself writing code like the following fairly frequently:

```
open System.Reflection
let ty = typeof<System.String> //suppose this type is actually unknown at compile time
seq {
    for name in ["a";"b";"c"] do
        yield ty.GetMethod(name)
} |> Seq.tryFind((<>)null)
```

instead of like

```
...
seq {
    for name in ["a";"b";"c"] do
        match ty.GetMethod(name) with
        | null -> ()
        | mi -> yield mi
} |> tryHead
```

Comment: Interesting speculations. :-) While I see your point in your last paragraph, I'm usually not filtering when I want the first element. That's why using `tryPick` feels awkward--it doesn't clearly express what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think that adding a `Seq.tryHead` extension would be a great idea then, folks will understand it immediately, and I generally don't see anything peculiar about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could define:

```
let seqTryHead s = Seq.tryPick Some s
```

It is of type `seq<'a> -> 'a option`. Note that I don't beta-reduce because of the generic value limitation.

Comment: This doesn't explicitly address my questions. I already mentioned this is what I'm doing.

Comment: This is the most idiomatic, since it is point-free (using only higher- functions). It isn't implemented because it isn't very common (though it is used).

Comment: Isn't it eta-reduction instead of beta-reduction? http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion